# ID generator for the Objects created

Tags: java, object, constructor

I need a class which creates Objects assigning an ID to each Object created. This ID is as usual an int attribute to the class. I want this value (ID) to be increased each time an Object is created and then to be assigned to that Object starting with 1. It strikes me that I need a static int attribute.

How can I initialize this static attribute?

Should I create a separate method to do the increment of the ID (as an ID generator) which is invoked inside the constructor?

What is in general the most effective and well-designed manner to implement that?

Comment: Just a comment: If you're in a server-side clustered environment this approach will fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like you mention use a `static int` for the id, and increment it when creating new objects.

```
class MyObject {

    private static int counter = 0;

    public final int objectId;

    MyObject() {
        this.objectId = counter++;
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to protect `counter++` if `MyObject` is created by multiple threads (for example using `AtomicInteger` as the other answers suggest).

Comment: I think the last statement must be : this.objectId = ++counter; . This way the first Object takes value 1 for ID, otherwise 0.

Comment: @arjacsoh Depends on your scenario, I would however prefer ids to start with 0. :)

Answer (score 8):

You could also try java.util.concurrent.AtomicInteger, which generates IDs in

1. a atomic way and
2. sequential

You may use this in a static context like:

```
private static final AtomicInteger sequence = new AtomicInteger();
private SequenceGenerator() {}

public static int next() {
    return sequence.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use `AtomicInteger`, which is thread-safe

```
class MyObject
{
    private static AtomicInteger uniqueId=new AtomicInteger();
    private int id;

    MyObject()
    {
       id=uniqueId.getAndIncrement();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you use getAndIncrement() instead of incrementAndGet()? Is it only a difference between var++ and ++var?

Comment: @EarthMind If you use `getAndIncrement()`, the IDs start from zero but if you use `incrementAndGet()`, the IDs start from one