# Infinite recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following code:

```
public void generateTree(Node myNode) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        //Creating child node
        Node child = new Node();

        //Setting new Depth
        child.setDepth(myNode.getDepth()+1);

        //Adding node to tree
        myTree.add(child);

        //If the game isn't over and we're not reached the maximum depth, recurse
        if(!isGameOver() && child.getDepth() < MAX_DEPTH)
            generateTree(child);
    }
}
```

Where basically MAX_DEPTH is an integer indicating the maximum depth I want to explore into a tree of moves in a game, getDepth() returns the depth of the node submitted as a parameter and setDepth sets the depth of the new node.

For some reason, it appears to generate an infinite recursion however... Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a print statement to get the value of Depth? Or using a debugger? If depth is not rising by 1 every sublevel then that would explain the infinite recursion.

Comment: What's `MAX_DEPTH`? Define infinite recursion - Does it just take forever or does it throw a `StackOverflowException`?

Comment: Dukeling I have set MAX_DEPTH to 2, and it seems to simply be going forever. The fact is that with a level of 2 it shouldn't need to examine more than 36 cases...

Comment: @Dario Panada Either you need to post all of your code or you need to use print/debugging to figure out the problem yourself. We are not psychic :)

Comment: Put `"System.out.println("start="+myNode.getDepth())"` on the first line and `"System.out.println("child="+child.getDepth())"` after setting the depth (or possibly include a unique ID to identify the node). This should give you a reasonable idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it's infinite. Maybe you're just running out of stack before you reach your end case.

Comment: Why are you doing it 6 times?

Comment: Dukeling how can I set a unique id? :)

Comment: @DarioPanada Put something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7660432/1711796) in `Node`'s constructor. Then print out this value together with `println`'s I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not infinite recursion. It is probably something else. This code works for me -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Node 
{

    private int depth;

    public static final int MAX_DEPTH = 2;

    private static List<Node> myTree = new ArrayList<Node>(); // for testing purposes

    public void generateTree(Node myNode) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            //Creating child node
            Node child = new Node();

            //Setting new Depth
            child.setDepth(myNode.getDepth()+1);

            //Adding node to tree
            myTree.add(child);

            //If the game isn't over and we're not reached the maximum depth, recurse
            if(child.getDepth() < MAX_DEPTH)
                generateTree(child);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Node node = new Node();

        Node myNode = new Node();
        myNode.setDepth(0);

        node.generateTree(myNode);

        System.out.println(myTree.size());

    }

    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    public void setDepth(int depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

}
```

The output I get is

```
42
```