# How to generate an incremental alphanumeric ID in java?(String ID)

Tags: java

I have a method for example,

```
public Order newOrder(Product prod, Supplier supp)
```

and need to generate an unique alphanumeric code with the format "ordn", where 'n' is a progressive number starting from 1, so every time a new order is added the ID will increment to "ord2" "ord3"...

How can I do this? Is it possible to do it by substringing?

I know how to generate an integer ID, but **this one is a String**, so my problem is more like how to increment an integer number in a string.

I tried to substring it to `String ocode = "ord" + n`, and just increment "n", but how can I assign this whole thing to the new order? or do I need a loop?
(the code has to be a String I guess, later there is a findOrder() method to retrieve a specific order by accepting the String code. <--not sure if it matters.)

btw I'm new to Java, and this is just a part of an exercise.

---

Solved, turns out the substring works...

Comment: what are your thoughts on implementing the logic you want?

Comment: So the question is how to generate an ascending integer sequence?

Comment: What should happen if your program is restarted. Start over from 1, or continue where it left off? Where would you want to save that? Usually, you let a database do stuff like that for you.

Comment: @Andreas you just need to maintain a shared (eventually) persistent state with atomic access in any form -- this does not have to be a DB. In fact if this is a microservice responsible for just providing incremental ids, then a DB would be a massive overkill for 1 int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ID generator for the Objects created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660409/id-generator-for-the-objects-created)

Comment: @OlegSklyar That one is Integer, but this is String, it's like I need to increment the 'n' in the String, and assign the string code to the new order.

Comment: @hikkirin One of the first things developers should learn is how to divide a complex problem (and yours is not even complex) into smaller independently solvable and testable parts. It is scary to think what your software may look like at the end if even a direct hint won't move you into that way of thinking. Your problem is a problem of incrementing an int. Solved million times (see duplicate link above or the answer below for a simple solution). Otherwise, it is a problem or parsing a string, which would be really bad design, but still, it would reduce to a problem of incrementing an int.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `static` ([tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)) int, and increment it by 1 for each order. The current value of the static counter is the id of the current order. When you need to return the string `ordn`, you return `"ord"+id`. Here's a simple example:

```
public class Order {

    static int sharedCounter = 0; //static, shared with ALL `Order` instances
    int orderId = 0; //Specific to particular `Order` instance

    public Order() {
       this.orderId = sharedCounter++;
    }

    public String getOrderId(){
       return "ord"+this.orderId;
    }
}
```

Note that the static ids will start with zero with each execution of the program. If you're writing it as an exercise, that's probably fine; but if you need to actually generate unique ids for some orders in the real world, then you'd need to store that information somewhere, probably a database.

Also, note that I've used a shared `int` in the example, which isn't thread safe. If thread safety is important, you'd need an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: You'd still need to return a string, though.

Comment: Thank you, I acturally did sth like this, but I need to return a string code and assign it to the new order.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`String newOrderId = "ord" + (Integer.parseInt(lastOrderId.substring(3)) + 1);`

Comment: Massively poor suggestion. Apart from the fact that you need to explicitly track your last order instance operating with strings, parsing them, slicing them when you actually have an int, what could be worse in one line of code?

Comment: [“Try this” answers are not useful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/4642212). Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are less useful for future readers and don’t explain the OP’s mistake or how to approach the problem.

Comment: @OlegSklyar, there's nothing wrong with this approach. It's all about a matter of opinion. I personally like this because i don't have to keep a track of an additional static variable which doesn't carry any business value. Think other perspectives before criticizing anything.

Comment: @Xufox, while I appreciate your suggestion, in this case, this is just a one liner self-explanatory code. OP hasn't made any mistakes. He is just asking for 'how-to'.

Comment: @VHS Your personal liking of your approach does not make it any better. My view is definitely subjective, I agree, but your solution is very poor by any objective measure one could possibly think of when one programming in any language: design, clarity, performance, robustness etc.

Comment: @OlegSklyar. You are wrong in your evaluation. My solution offers both brevity and clarity.

Comment: Very funny indeed. Good luck with submitting the code you write to critical code reviews. I am sure reviewers will share your views on problems like this one.