# how to set a value to an object without a parameter

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java programming and I want to rewrite the code below, but instead to set the id number myself, I want the id number to be set automatically in order to $1,2,3,...$ I know I have to use id as a static variable and I should increment with id++ in the constructor. The problem is I don't know how to make this automatically. I want that each student has his own id, so when I write for example robert.getId() it gives me his id, but I don't want the id to be a parameter, then my object construction would be:

```
Students robert = new Students("Robert Smith", 8, 3500);
```

So I only need to provide the name, grade and tuition with the id set automatically to robert object, how can I do that?

```
package schoolManagementSystem;

public class Students 
{
    //Instance Variables
    
    private int id,grade, tuition;
    private String name;
    
    
    //Constructors
    
    /**
     * constructs an object of the class Student
     * @param id id of the student
     * @param name name of the student
     * @param grade grade of the student
     * @param tuition tuition the student has to pay
     */
    public Students(int id,String name, int grade,int tuition)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.tuition = tuition;
    }
public int getId()
{
    return id;
}
}
```

Comment: is the java you write connected to the database?

Comment: @Spectric not at all. I didn't know my question wasn't clear enough. I'm sorry. I want to have a variable id linked to the object but without necessarily have to write it as a parameter, did you follow me?

Comment: @hirarqi no, that's just a very simple program.

Comment: Your code is OK right now. What's stopping you from automatically setting the id?

Comment: Someone mentioned AtomicInteger [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660538/9412863). See if it helps.

Comment: @Spectric I don't know how to set it

Comment: @user804406 I don't understand what you want the id to be.

Comment: @Spectric suppose I created a getId() method to get the id of the objects of this class. So I want to construct the object robert("Robert Smith", 8, 3500) and when I call robert.getId() it gives me the id number sets automatically to 1. did it help?

Comment: @Spectric when I create another object mary("Mary Robbs", 10, 2600) and when I call a getter method getId to mary, mary.getId, it gives me the id =2, and so on

Comment: @user804406 You'll need something to store all the records then. Do you understand databases?

Comment: @user804406 In this context, I don't think so

Comment: Create a static int, call it baseId. Initialize it to your starting id. The id is assigned in the constructor like ``id = baseId++;``. Of course, this may fail if you decide to use multiple threads.

Comment: @user804406 I don't think you can create this without dynamic technology. Do you know how to store things in files?

Comment: @NomadMaker I think it worked! thank you very much!!!

Comment: @user804406, I think it worked

Comment: @NomadMaker the only strange thing is when I declare baseId = 0 and write in the constructor id = baseId++, the first id object is set to 0, it should start at 1, no?

Comment: Then set baseId to 1. This number will be your first I'd, because ``baseId++`` increments baseId after it is used in the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Let me know

```
import java.util.*;

public class Students
{
    //Instance Variables

    private int id,grade, tuition;
    private String name;

    private static Set<Integer> idSet = new HashSet<>();
    private static Map<Integer, Students> db = new HashMap<>();


    //Constructors
    /**
     * constructs an object of the class Student
     * @param name name of the student
     * @param grade grade of the student
     * @param tuition tuition the student has to pay
     */
    public Students(String name, int grade,int tuition)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.tuition = tuition;
    }

    public int getId() {
        if (idSet.contains(0)) {
            int max = Collections.max(idSet);
            int newMax = max + 1;
            db.put(newMax, this);
            idSet.add(newMax);
            return newMax;
        } else {
            int max = 0;
            db.put(max, this);
            idSet.add(max);
            return max;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AtomicInteger and getAndIncrement() method your program will look like as follows

```
public class Students 
{
    //Instance Variables
    private  AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    private int id,grade, tuition;
    private String name;
    
    
    //Constructors
    
    /**
     * constructs an object of the class Student
     * @param id id of the student
     * @param name name of the student
     * @param grade grade of the student
     * @param tuition tuition the student has to pay
     */
    public Students(int id,String name, int grade,int tuition)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.tuition = tuition;
    }
public int getId()
{
    return  count.getAndIncrement();

}
}
```